Creating a "view" of a sibling class avoiding unnecessary copy
Consider this (simplified) class hierarchy in a c++98 source
(godbolt):
class Shape
{
 public:
    virtual class CurvilinearShape as_curvilinear_shape() const =0;
};

class CurvilinearShape : public Shape
{
    // ...
 public:
    virtual CurvilinearShape as_curvilinear_shape() const
       {
        return *this;
       }
};

class PolygonShape : public Shape
{
    // ...
 public:
    virtual CurvilinearShape as_curvilinear_shape() const
       {
        CurvilinearShape curv_shape;
        // Convert...
        return curv_shape;
       }
};

A PolygonShape can be easily converted to a CurvilinearShape.
The reason that led to those two distinct classes is that a PolygonShape
has a simplified description that can be processed by simpler machines,
while more advanced ones can process the more generic CurvilinearShape
descriptor:
void work_curvilinear_shape(CurvilinearShape const&);

In this case it's very handy to process a sequence of base Shape
items without worrying about the actual descriptor used, the virtual
member function as_curvilinear_shape() was introduced just for that:
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<Shape*> shapes;
    for(std::vector<Shape*>::const_iterator it=shapes.begin(); it!=shapes.end(); ++it)
       {
        work_curvilinear_shape( (*it)->as_curvilinear_shape() );
       }
}

This works, but has the problem of the unnecessary copy construction that
takes place each time CurvilinearShape::as_curvilinear_shape() is called
(incidentally the majority of the times).
Although this seems a fairly common use case I cannot find a name
for it, do you know it?
I'm searching for a better approach that avoids the unnecessary copy in case
the item is already a CurvilinearShape instance, maybe one of you can put me on the right track?

How about having as_curvilinear_shape() returns a CurvilinearShape& reference? Then CurvilinearShape::as_curvilinear_shape() won't make a copy anymore. But PolygonShape would need to hold an internal CurvilinearShape member to satisfy the reference.

@RemyLebeau That would be a viable option! The disadvantage would be the cost of the CurvilinearShape member, I wonder if there's another possible alternative.

Off the top of my head, this sounds like returning something like boost::variant<CurvilinearShape, CurvilinearShape const&> can work (hopefully it isn't accessed too much, so the need to write many visitors won't come up).

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I'm not currently including boost library but the variant approach is worthy of further consideration

@MatG - HolyBlackCat already beat me to it, but you can definitely write your own choice type for this. Alignment might be tricky, but you can theoretically hold a union of raw storage + pointer and operate in terms of that.

C++98 is an awful language, prefer C over it for almost any job. Having said that, have you tried making CurvilinearShape a pure interface? PolygonalShape foo for that matter. Class Polygon would implement both while class Curve would implement only the second one.

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Probably that's the way I'll follow

@n.m.couldbeanAI If I understood well, it would be somewhat similar to have a CurvilinearShape member in PolygonShape. By the way, C is a wonderful tool, but I'm not using it in this project.

"it would be somewhat similar to have a CurvilinearShape member in PolygonShape" not really. It depends on how your interfaces are structured. A well designed interface should not need any such thing

A (somewhat cumbersome) solution is to give as_curvilinear_shape the following signature:
const CurvilinearShape &as_curvilinear_shape(CurvilinearShape &storage) const;

If it's already the right shape, return *this and leave storage unchanged. If a conversion is needed, assign the conversion result to storage and return a reference to storage.
Or you might want to create a helper class and return it:
struct CurvilinearShapeOrRef
{
    CurvilinearShape storage; // or `std::optional`/`boost::optional`.
    const CurvilinearShape *ptr_override = nullptr; // C++98 can't do this, make a constructor.

    const CurvilinearShape &get() const {return ptr_override ? *ptr_override : storage;}
};

